# JavaScript word guessing game issue: the same letter won't populate multiple times once the letter key is pressed

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-listener, dom-manipulation

I have my word guessing game setup so that when the user presses the correct letter, the corresponding underscore is replaced with the letter. However, I can't seem to get the same letter to populate multiple times. Example: the word "Pennywise" has two of the letter 'n', but when the letter is pressed only one 'n' will populate no matter how many times I press the letter.

```
// Global Variables
// ================================================================================================================================================
// Create an array of words
var word = [
"michael myers", 
"freddy krueger", 
"jason voorhees", 
"xenomorph", 
"pinhead", 
"ghostface", 
"hannibal lector", 
"pennywise", 
"leatherface", 
"chucky", 
"jack torrance"
]

var rightLetter = [];
var wrongLetter = [];
var underScore = [];

// Choose word randomly
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length);
    var randWord = word[randNum];
    console.log(randWord);

// DOM manipulation
var docUnderScore = document.getElementsByClassName("underscore");
var docRightGuess = document.getElementsByClassName("rightGuess");
var docWrongGuess = document.getElementsByClassName("wrongGuess");


// ================================================================================================================================================
// Main
// ================================================================================================================================================
// Create underscore based on length of word
    var generateUnderscore = () => {
        for ( var i = 0; i < randWord.length; i++) {
            underScore.push("_");
        }
        return underScore;
    }

// Get user guess
    document.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
        var keyWord = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        // if user's guess is correct    
        if (randWord.indexOf(keyWord) === -1) {
        // replace underscore with correct letter
            underScore[randWord.indexOf(keyWord)] = keyWord;
            docUnderScore[0].innerHTML = underScore.join(" ");

        // check to see if user word matches guess
            if (underScore.join("") === randWord) {
                alert("You Survived!");
            }
        }
        // if user's guess is incorrect     
        else {
            wrongLetter.push(keyWord);
            docWrongGuess[0].innerHTML = wrongLetter;
        }

    });

    docUnderScore[0].innerHTML = generateUnderscore().join(" ");
```

Comment: `.indexOf()` return the 1st occurrence of the searched pattern, not all the indexes. You should continue finding indexes (on the rest of the string) until no others are found.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you won't proceed further using `randWord.indexOf(keyWord)` as each time it fetches the first occurence of the letter you want to find, instead you could maintain a counter and match letter each time `keydown` event is fired, if it doe match then increment it to proceed:

```js
// Create an array of words
var word = [
  "michael myers",
  "freddy krueger",
  "jason voorhees",
  "xenomorph",
  "pinhead",
  "ghostface",
  "hannibal lector",
  "pennywise",
  "leatherface",
  "chucky",
  "jack torrance"
];

var rightLetter = [];
var wrongLetter = [];
var underScore = [];
var counter = 0;

// Choose word randomly
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length);
var randWord = word[7];
console.log(randWord);

// DOM manipulation
var docUnderScore = document.getElementsByClassName("underscore");
var docRightGuess = document.getElementsByClassName("rightGuess");
var docWrongGuess = document.getElementsByClassName("wrongGuess");

// Create underscore based on length of word
var generateUnderscore = () => {
  for (var i = 0; i < randWord.length; i++) {
    underScore.push("_");
  }
  return underScore;
}

// Get user guess
document.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
  var keyWord = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  // if user's guess is correct    
  if (randWord[counter] == keyWord) {
    // replace underscore with correct letter
    underScore[counter] = keyWord;
    docUnderScore[0].innerHTML = underScore.join(" ");

    // check to see if user word matches guess
    if (underScore.join("") === randWord) {
      console.log("You Survived!");
    }
    counter++;
  }
  // if user's guess is incorrect     
  else {
    wrongLetter.push(keyWord);
    docWrongGuess[0].innerHTML = wrongLetter;
  }
});

docUnderScore[0].innerHTML = generateUnderscore().join(" ");
```

```html
<div class="underscore"></div>
<div class="rightGuess"></div>
<div class="wrongGuess"></div>
```